# Override SugarCRM Module.php in Ext/Include/module.ext.php cause of Memory Issue

Tags: memory, overriding, sugarcrm

i want to override module.php core file of sugarcrm for upgrade-safe customization of bean class.its give memory issue jsut as PermGen Exception of java.

and after changing in php.ini

```
memory_limit=128M ; its by - default ,
```

and i tried 256M,512M,1024M but problem remain same.

so can any one tell me what is fix for this issue?

My Aim is : **Override Module.php as Upgrade-Safe.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customize a core file, do so in the custom directory.

Check out `/custom/Extension/application/Ext/Include` directory, these files build into the single `modules.ext.php` file in the `/custom/application/Ext/Include/` directory. This stores all of your bean files and references to bean classes.

I don't get what the memory limit has to do with this, can you explain?

updated - just noticed this is old - you probably figured out what you need by now.